# Symfony2 / doctrine2 annotation for: either enter both fields or none?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine, validation

Is there a way of demanding through annotations in Symfony2 or doctrine2: if you have populated field A, then you must also specify field B?

In my case the user can specify a type of cron job they want to schedule. If the type is odbc, then at least one db-table must be selected. If it is any other type of cron job, no table selection is required (or even meaningful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure an assert/callback in your annotation that points to a callback function that verifies your entity data.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * ...
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"validateDB"})
 */
class Item
{
    protected $type;
    protected $table; 

    public function validateDB(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        $path = $context->getPropertyPath();
        if ($this->type == 'odbc' and empty($this->table)) {
            // ".type" is the property name where you want the error to appear
            // in the form.
            $context->setPropertyPath($path . '.type'); 
            $context->addViolation("ODBC table must be specified.", array(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's what I wanted. Thanks Lifo!